# Detail on the usage of 婚儀 to refer to a spousal relationship?

Tags: meaning, nuances, definitions

I was looking up 婚儀 on ejje to understand the differences between it and 結婚式 when I found a third definition for it which confused me

> 3) union, spousal relationship, matrimony, wedlock, marriage
>
> 自発的に人生（または離婚まで）のために結ばれた夫婦である状態 (the state of being a married couple voluntarily joined for life (or until divorce))
>
> -a long and happy marriage 長く幸せな結婚生活
>
> -God bless this union 神は、この夫婦に恩恵を与える

As far as I know, 婚儀 refers strictly to the marriage ceremony itself, not the union between two people, and I haven't found any other usages like or definitions like this in other dictionaries. Is this an error, or an old usage? Or can 婚儀 be used in place of 結婚, and in what circumstances?

Comment: The data you saw seems to be from [here](http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/wnja/). There's a disclaimer says: "We estimate that this release package contains errors in 5% of all entries..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's an error. Never heard it being used to refer to the concept of the marriage.

Generally 婚儀 is just an archaic version of 結婚式. Almost always, wedding ceremonies will be called 結婚式. It could be used e.g. if you are referring to the emperor's wedding ceremony etc.